# Best way to monitor ubuntu desktop machine

Tags: ubuntu, monitoring, desktop

I'm trying to find a simple solution to monitor all desktop machines of my network (~ 35 Ubuntu desktop). I do not want to use passive monitoring like Munin or Cacti but with an active agent on the desktop, i wish only keep a day or a week of data retention i do not need more.

In fact i plan to use New Relic Server to monitor as my servers. Is there a best way ?

Comment: It depends upon what you want to monitor on your desktops?

Comment: CPU, Memory, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, NewRelic is a simple and good solution.